# Python and FastAPI live HTML Interface

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a Python application that compares two files. if i add something in one file and save it, there is a difference. its just a small helper to develope something different.

I would like to show that difference as fast as possible in a html file that i use as an interface. I tried FastAPI and my template is rendering correctly, its also taking the variables im sending but how can i trigger an update of only one variable in that html file?

```
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)  
async def index(request: Request):
   return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {
        "request": request,
        "difference": difference,
        "other": variable
        })
```

i would like to avoid calling avery second but would like to trigger an update only when it happens.

If using websocket, is it possible to wait for another function to send data that then will be "forwarded" to the html/js? The Example waits until the js sends text.

```
 while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Data: {data}")
```

Comment: Tried using Websocket? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72070914/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626324/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804)

Comment: i have made one version with websocket but then i thought that this might be somehow over the top. But it seems the way to go.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) helpful as well

Comment: looks promising. im trying to simulate this with catching the keyboard but that seems to create totally new problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I used `from pynput import keyboard` to simulate Variable changes e.g. when pressing a button `status` was set to True and `data` got some content. The keyboard listener was blocking everything else. i had to add some returns, now it is working for simulation (which i wont need later).

Its not beautiful and throws errors if you hit buttons that are not defined and im pretty shure that this also could have been solved by a thread but for now it worked:

```
# Keyboard
def on_release(key):
    global status
    global msg

    try:
        key_char = key.char

        if key_char  == 'a':
            status = True
            msg = "Answer A"
            print(str(status) + " | " + msg)
            return
        if key_char  == 'b':
            status = True
            msg = "Answer B"
            print(str(status) + " | " + msg)
            return
        if key_char  == 'c':
            status = True
            msg = "Answer C"
            print(str(status) + " | " + msg)
            return
        if key_char  == 'D':
            status = True
            msg = "Answer D"
            print(str(status) + " | " + msg)
            return
        else:
            status = False
            msg = ""
            return

    except AttributeError:
        key_char = key
        return

# Keyboard listener
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release)

# Start listener
listener.start()
```

The important part of the code now looks like this:

```
# Main Website
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)  
async def index(request: Request):
   return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {
        "request": request,
        "number": number
        })

# WebSocket Start
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    
    await websocket.accept()
    global status
    global msg

    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            if status:
                await websocket.send_text(msg) #Should be send every time status changes to True
                status = False
    except Exception:
        pass
```

what also worked:

```
# Main Website
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)  
async def index(request: Request):
   return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {
        "request": request,
        "number": number
        })


async def monitor_variable(websocket):
    global status
    global msg

    while True:
        if status:
            print("Old Status: " + str(status))
            await websocket.send_text(msg)
            status = False
            print("New Status: " + str(status))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # You can adjust the sleep time as needed


# WebSocket Start
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    
    await websocket.accept()
    
    # Start a thread to run the monitor_variable function
    t = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(monitor_variable(websocket),))
    t.start()
```

So everytime the status changes, a message with content will be sent.
maybe there are better solutions but this works for now or better say: both solutions work

Comment: Also an alternative approach for me would be Server-Sent Events.