# The messages in my Fastapi websocket are stuck and get only processed when I close my frontend, i.e. interrupt the connection

Tags: websocket, mqtt, fastapi

It's the first time I'm working with websocket connections and I can't fully explain this problem. I'm trying to connect to my websocket via the frontend. Then I receive the corresponding outputs in the frontend and my backend that the connection works.

Frontend console:

```
Connection successful
```

Backend console:

```
INFO:     connection open
```

Then I'm trying to send a message to the backend with a JSON array and I then want to process this in the backend to connect to specific MQTT topics. However, I don't receive any output for this in the backend.

Frontend console:

```
Message sent:  [{"connectionID":0,"scanner":[{"scannerID":"001"}],"projector":[{"projectorID":"001"}]}]
```

Backend console:
Nothing

But as soon as I update the frontend, i.e. interrupt the connection, the message is processed and the output is displayed in the backend. The message seems to be stuck until I disconnect.

Backend console:

```
2024-01-11 08:28:47 INFO:     connection closed
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Here we continue after receiving.
2024-01-11 08:28:47 put item:  [{"connectionID":0,"scanner":[{"scannerID":"001"}],"projector":[{"projectorID":"001"}]}]
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Here I am in while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Processed WebSocket message: [{"connectionID":0,"scanner":[{"scannerID":"001"}],"projector":[{"projectorID":"001"}]}]
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Subscribed to MQTT topic: /scanner/001/event
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Subscribed to MQTT topic: /projector/001/event
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Processed WebSocket message: [{"connectionID":0,"scanner":[{"scannerID":"001"}],"projector":[{"projectorID":"001"}]}]
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start try block inside while true block
2024-01-11 08:28:47 Start receiving messages from the websocket
2024-01-11 08:28:47 WebSocket was disconnected from the client.
```

The following code snippet shows the relevant code in my Vuejs frontend:

```
function connectToWebSocket() {
    socket.value = new WebSocket(import.meta.env.VITE_WEBSOCKET_ADDRESS +"order_initialization");

    socket.value.onmessage = (event) => {
        message.value = event.data;
        console.log("Message received from backend: ", event.data);
    };

    socket.value.onopen = () => {
        console.log("Connection successful.");
    };

    socket.value.onclose = () => {
        console.log("Connection closed.");
        socket.value = null;
    };

    socket.value.onerror = (error) => {
        console.error("Error: ", error);
    };
}

function sendConnectionToWebSocket() {
    if (socket.value && (socket.value.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN)) {
        const messageToSend = JSON.stringify(connections.value);
        socket.value.send(messageToSend);
        console.log("Message sent: ", messageToSend);
    } else {
        console.log("WebSocket not connected.");
    }
}
```

And this is the websocket in my FastAPI backend. I run the backend inside a docker container.

```
from fastapi import WebSocket, APIRouter
from starlette.websockets import WebSocketDisconnect
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
from enum import Enum, auto
import os
import json
import asyncio

router = APIRouter()

class WebSocketState(Enum):
    CONNECTED = auto()
    DISCONNECTED = auto()
    ERROR = auto()

class AsyncQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = asyncio.Queue()

    async def put(self, item):
        await self._queue.put(item)
        print('put item: ', item)

    async def get(self):
        return await self._queue.get()

    def empty(self):
        return self._queue.empty()
    
env_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

mqtt_address=os.getenv("mqtt_address")
mqtt_messages = AsyncQueue()
websocket_messages = AsyncQueue()
last_connections_data = None
subscribed_topics = []

async def on_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    # This function is called when an MQTT message is received
    await mqtt_messages.put(message.payload.decode())
    print(f"Received MQTT message: {message.payload} on topic {message.topic}")

def on_mqtt_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connection to MQTT successfully established")
    else:
        print(f"Error connecting to MQTT. Return code: {rc}")

# Abonnieren von Topics
def subscribe_to_topic(client, topic):
    client.subscribe(topic)
    subscribed_topics.append(topic)
    print(f"Subscribed to MQTT topic: {topic}")

# Entfernen aller Abonnements
def unsubscribe_all(client):
    if subscribed_topics:
        client.unsubscribe(subscribed_topics)
        subscribed_topics.clear()

# Configure the client
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
mqtt_client.on_message = on_mqtt_message
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_mqtt_connect
mqtt_client.connect(mqtt_address, 1883, 60)
mqtt_client.loop_start()

@router.websocket("/ws/order_initialization")
async def order_initialization_websocket(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()

    # Set the WebsocketState to CONNECTED
    ws_state = WebSocketState.CONNECTED
    global last_connections_data
    global subscribed_topics

    print('Start try block')

    try:
        print('Start while true block')
        while True:
            print('Start try block inside while true block')
            try:
                print('Start receiving messages from the websocket')
                # Receiving data from WebSocket and adding it to the queue
                data = await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.receive_text(), timeout=1.0)
                print('Here we continue after receiving.')
                await websocket_messages.put(data)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                # No new messages received, check the MQTT queue
                print('No new messages received, check the MQTT queue')
            
            print('Process, so this output is just before the while not websocket_messages.empty()')
            # Processing the WebSocket messages from the queue
            while not websocket_messages.empty():
                print('Here I am in while not websocket_messages.empty()')
                message = await websocket_messages.get()
                print(f"Processed WebSocket message: {message}")

                # Process the websocket message when a connection is passed
                if "connectionID" in message:
                    connections = json.loads(message)

                    # Check if the message is different from the last one
                    if message != last_connections_data:
                        # Remove old subscriptions if any
                        if subscribed_topics:
                            unsubscribe_all(client=mqtt_client)

                        # Subscribe to the new topics
                        for connection in connections:
                            for scanner in connection['scanner']:
                                scanner_topic = f"/scanner/{scanner['scannerID']}/event"
                                subscribe_to_topic(mqtt_client, scanner_topic)

                            for projector in connection['projector']:
                                projector_topic = f"/projector/{projector['projectorID']}/event"
                                subscribe_to_topic(mqtt_client, projector_topic)

                # Processing the websocket message when the calibration should be started

                print(f"Processed WebSocket message: {message}")

            # Processing the MQTT messages
            while not mqtt_messages.empty():
                mqtt_message = await mqtt_messages.get()
                await websocket.send_text(mqtt_message)
                print(f"Sent MQTT message to WebSocket client: {mqtt_message}")

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print("WebSocket was disconnected from the client.")
        ws_state = WebSocketState.DISCONNECTED

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"WebSocket Error: {e}")
        ws_state = WebSocketState.ERROR

    finally:
        # Check whether the connection is already closed
        if not ws_state == WebSocketState.DISCONNECTED:
            await websocket.close()
```

I don't understand this error. How can I prevent messages from getting stuck?

I investigated whether it changes anything if I wait half a minute before sending the message from the frontend. This caused it to actually be processed once. However, if I send it again, regardless of the waiting time, it will only be processed again when I interrupt the connection.

I tried to narrow down the problem using debug output and experimented with different queues. I also checked in the dev tools in the frontend whether the messages are being sent.

I also checked that the broker is working properly.

Maybe it's related to the MQTT connection, before that I could exchange test messages from backend and frontend.

Comment: Related answers that might be helpful can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780637/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74639030/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72070914/17865804)